# Mips: Printout multiple values in 2 rows

Tags: assembly, mips

I have a byte array and I want to print that out with syscall.
The first 3 bytes in the first row and the bytes 4 to 6 in the second row.

The expected output is:

```
 0  1  2 
 3  4  5
```

But the print out looks like this:

```
 0
  1
  2
 
 3
  4
  5
```

It seems that every print out of a byte also includes a newline.
Here is the coding:

```
.data
     board: .byte '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'
     cell: .asciiz ""
     newline: .asciiz "\n"
     space: .asciiz " "

.text
.globl main

main:
    la  $a0 board
    jal drawBoard

drawBoard:
    la $t0, ($a0)            # load the address of board byte array 
    la $t1, cell             # load address of cell string

    #### ROW 1 ################################################
        
    #*** Cell 1 ******************************************
    # Space
    li $v0,4
    la $a0, space
    syscall
    # Byte 0 from board
    lbu  $t2, 0($t0)         # load the first byte of $t0 (board) into $t2
    sb   $t2, 0($t1)         # save $t2 into first byte of $t1 (cell)    
    li $v0,4
    la $a0, cell
    syscall
    # Space
    li $v0,4
    la $a0, space
    syscall

    #*** Cell 2 ******************************************
    # Space
    li $v0,4
    la $a0, space
    syscall
    # Byte 1 from board
    lbu  $t2, 1($t0)         # load the first byte of $t0 (board) into $t2
    sb   $t2, 0($t1)         # save $t2 into first byte of $t1 (cell)    
    li $v0,4
    la $a0, cell
    syscall
    # Space
    li $v0,4
    la $a0, space
    syscall

    #*** Cell 3 ******************************************
    # Space
    li $v0,4
    la $a0, space
    syscall
    # Byte 2 from board
    lbu  $t2, 2($t0)         # load the first byte of $t0 (board) into $t2
    sb   $t2, 0($t1)         # save $t2 into first byte of $t1 (cell)    
    li $v0,4
    la $a0, cell
    syscall
    # Space
    li $v0,4
    la $a0, space
    syscall
 
    #*** Newline ******************************************
    li $v0,4
    la $a0, newline
    syscall
    
    #### ROW 2 ################################################
        
    #*** Cell 4 ******************************************
    # Space
    li $v0,4
    la $a0, space
    syscall
    # Byte 3 from board
    lbu  $t2, 3($t0)         # load the first byte of $t0 (board) into $t2
    sb   $t2, 0($t1)         # save $t2 into first byte of $t1 (cell)    
    li $v0,4
    la $a0, cell
    syscall
    # Space
    li $v0,4
    la $a0, space
    syscall

    #*** Cell 5 ******************************************
    # Space
    li $v0,4
    la $a0, space
    syscall
    # Byte 4 from board
    lbu  $t2, 4($t0)         # load the first byte of $t0 (board) into $t2
    sb   $t2, 0($t1)         # save $t2 into first byte of $t1 (cell)    
    li $v0,4
    la $a0, cell
    syscall
    # Space
    li $v0,4
    la $a0, space
    syscall

    #*** Cell 6 ******************************************
    # Space
    li $v0,4
    la $a0, space
    syscall
    # Byte 5 from board
    lbu  $t2, 5($t0)         # load the first byte of $t0 (board) into $t2
    sb   $t2, 0($t1)         # save $t2 into first byte of $t1 (cell)    
    li $v0,4
    la $a0, cell
    syscall
    # Space
    li $v0,4
    la $a0, space
    syscall
```

I would appreciate any help!

Thanks in advance,
Vincent

################ EDIT #########################

When I switch the declartions of space and newline, the output looks almost right!
But between the number is one space too much:

```
 0   1   2  
 3   4   5
```

THIS IS REALLY STRANGE!!!
How is it possible that the order of the data declaration is changing the output?

Thanks, Vincent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cell` is an empty string, i.e. just a NUL-terminator character. So when you store a character to that address, you're overwriting the NUL-terminator. This then causes the string immediately following `cell` to also be printed when you print `cell`.

One way of fixing this would be to change the declaration of `cell` to `.asciiz " "`. Or you could skip `cell` altogether and use system call 11 to print a single character (which you must load into `$a0`).